# Validate multiple values from JSON response

Tags: jmeter

JSON Response:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "roleId": "API_EPX_TESTING",
                "code": "API_EPX_TESTING",
                "status": "active",
                "features": [
                    {
                        "id": "Current_Day_1_0",
                        "name": "Current Day V1.0",
                        "code": "Current_Day_1_0",
                        "identifier": "Current_Day_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to land on current day on one button click",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Send_Communication_1_0",
                        "name": "Send Communication V1.0",
                        "code": "Send_Communication_1_0",
                        "identifier": "Send_Communication_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to send text message  email  letter communications to patient for an appointment",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "View_Warning_Note_1_0",
                        "name": "View Warning Note V1.0",
                        "code": "View_Warning_Note_1_0",
                        "identifier": "View_Warning_Note_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to view warning note icon on a given appointment",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Reschedule_Prompt_1_0",
                        "name": "Reschedule Prompt V1.0",
                        "code": "Reschedule_Prompt_1_0",
                        "identifier": "Reschedule_Prompt_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to one click and reschedule an appointment",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "View_Outstanding_1_0",
                        "name": "View Outstanding V1.0",
                        "code": "View_Outstanding_1_0",
                        "identifier": "View_Outstanding_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to view outstanding balance icon on a given appointment",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "New_ePractice_Diary_1_0",
                        "name": "New ePractice Diary V1.0",
                        "code": "New_ePractice_Diary_1_0",
                        "identifier": "New_ePractice_Diary_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows user to access new ePractice",
                        "status": "active"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Limited_ICE_Access_1_0",
                        "name": "Limited ICE Access",
                        "code": "Limited_ICE_Access_1_0",
                        "identifier": "Limited_ICE_Access_1_0",
                        "description": "Allows to check ICE subscription",
                        "status": "active"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        "success": true,
        "statusCode": 200
    }
```

I need to validate multiple 'identifier' values from  the response and not all values.
Example: Current_Day_1_0 & View_Warning_Note_1_0 , whether these values exist in the response or not

I have tried with JSON extractor and Response Assertion but I'm not able to validate specific values from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 [JSON Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion):

1. Validate presence of `Current_Day_1_0` identifier:

   [image]

   text version of the JSONPath expression just in case:

   ```
   $.data[0].features[?(@.identifier=='Current_Day_1_0')]
   ```
2. And similarly validate presence of `View_Warning_Note_1_0` identifier:

   [image]

   and text version:

   ```
   $.data[0].features[?(@.identifier=='View_Warning_Note_1_0')]
   ```

More information:

- [JSONPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath?tab=readme-ov-file#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your time, I have tried but it's not failing even I give wrong value.

Comment: Thanks Madhu for your valuable comment, I've tested the use case **again** using [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) and the [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) configured exactly like above and it fails for me if the if `identifier` attribute with text of `Current_Day_1_0` is not present. Here is the [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oXQ1.gif). So please double check your configuration.